# Define what it means for $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be analytic at $z_0$,

Tags: complex-analysis

Define precisely what it means for a function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be analytic at $z_0$

Either of these satisfy the definition of $f$?

$1.$ If $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z=z_0$ and in some small region around $z_0$, then we say $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=z_0$.

2.Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $z_0 \in\mathbb{C}$. If $\exists R > 0$ and $c_0,c_1,c_2$...$\in \mathbb{C}$ such that the power series $\sum_{k \geq 0}c_k(z-z_0)^k$ convergest in $D[z_0,R]$ and agrees with $f(z)$ in $D[z_0,R]$ then $f$ is analytic at $z_0$.

Comment: Yes, those are equivalent (for complex functions) definitions of being analytic. I think I learned the definition of analytic as number 2, and then the fact that it is equivalent to 1 as a theorem.

Comment: The first definition is wrong. It is not enough that $f$ will be differentiable at $z_0$, its needed that $f$ will be **infinite** times differentiable at $z_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition 1) defines what is called a **holomorphic** function.  (It is better to say that the complex derivative $f'(z)$ exists in a neighborhood of $z_0$, because the concept of '' some small region around $z_0$'' is not well defined).

The definition  2) defines  an **analytic** function.  This is a concept that can be used also for functions of real variables (or other variables that are not complex numbers).

The fact that a complex function  is holomorphic iff it is analytic is a ''great and beatiful'' [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions) of the complex calculus.

Comment: +1 I'd never heard of this distinction between the usage of the words "holomorphic" and "analytic". I'd always known the two words were synonymous in complex analysis and that the two definitions were equivalent, but I always considered the choice of words to be rather arbitrary (in school I learned both definitions as "analytic"). The distinction highlights the unobvious link between the topological notion and the analytical notion. Very enlightening. Thanks!